# why few records return in How many WP_User created in particular date

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

```
SELECT *
 FROM `wp_users` group by date(user_registered),month(user_registered)
```

---

their are 4 records in table , but query return only one record from each date.

```
Table: wp_user
abc 2018-08-09 0400
aaa 2018-08-09 0900
xyz 2018-08-10 0600
eee 2018-08-10 0900

Query Result.
abc 2018-08-09 0400
xyz 2018-08-10 0600
```

I want to see how many users create in each day.

Comment: `SELECT date(user_registered),month(user_registered), COUNT(*)  FROM wp_users group by date(user_registered),month(user_registered) `

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement with help of MYSQL [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(`user`) AS numberOfuser, user_registered
 FROM `wp_user` GROUP BY DATE(user_registered),MONTH(user_registered);
```